# When are two quotient groups isomorphic if the quotient part are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and two isomorphic normal subgroups $H_1\cong H_2\subset G$. When does $G/H_1  \cong G/H_2$ hold?
I heard one sufficient and necessary condition is that if there exists an automorphism $\sigma:G\rightarrow G$ such that $\sigma(H_1)=H_2$.  One direction is trivial, what about the other direction, i.e. if two quotient groups isomophic then there exists such an automorphism?
Actually , the question can be diverted into a kind of "extension of mapping" problem, i.e. given isomoprhic $\phi: G/H_1\rightarrow G/H_2,\psi : H_1\rightarrow H_2$,  how can we construct an isomoprhism $h:G\rightarrow G$ such that the corresponding map of short exact sequence forms a commutative diagram?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that the condition you mention is necessary:

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}}\times \mathbb{Z}^{\times \mathbb{N}}$, $H_1=0 \times (\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}} \subseteq G$ and $H_2=0 \times( 2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}}\subseteq G $.

Then $G/H_1 =(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}}$ and $G/H_2=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\times \mathbb{N}}$ via a bijection $\mathbb{N}\coprod \mathbb{N} \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{N}$. Also clearly $H_1 \simeq H_2$, by the map that multiplies all the entries by $2$.

However, there cannot be any automorphism of $G$ that takes $H_1$ to $H_2$: The reason is that $H_1$ is a direct summand of $G$, i.e. has a complementary subgroup, while $H_2$ is not.